# normal subgroup and order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $G$ is a finite group and $N$ is a subgroup of G so that $|G| = 2|N|$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I know that if $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$ then $|G/N|=|G|/|N|$, but I don't see how $|G| = 2|N|$ which mean $|G/N|=2$ can guarantee that $N$ is normal in $G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $g\in G$ we have $g\in N$ or $g\notin N$. If $g\in N$ then $Ng=N=gN$ and so $N^g=N$. If  $g\notin N$ hen since $[G:N]=2$ so we can write $$G=N\cup Ng=N\cup gN$$ and so we necessarily have $$gN=Ng$$ Note that speaking about $[G:N]$ does not mean that $G/N$ is a group in general.

Comment: how do we know this " If $g∈N$ then $Ng=N=gN$ ", we don't know if $N$ is Abelian or not.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: We don't know and have and need $N$ be abelian. $Ng=gN$ and the equality you have written is wrong here. Note the last sentence of another answer. It says what we need to have $Ng=gN$.

Comment: Nice, Babak! $\checkmark^{{\checkmark}^\checkmark}$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Dear :-)

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Since $N$ is a subgroup (it does not matter whether $N$ is normal or not), we know that $|G/N|=|G|/|N|=2$. Then we can write $G/N=\{N, hN\}$ for any $h\in G-N$. Since there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of left and right cosets, we also have $G/N=\{N, Nh\}$. But then $hN=Nh$, and so $N$ is normal.

Comment: thank you too, much appreciated.